# Selenium webdriver is opening the browser, but not opening the given url

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

[This is the screenshot of the error I'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1mIz.png)

I have recently taken up the task to learn functional testing and web automation using selnium webdriver with python. When I execute my code, the web browser opens up, but the URL doesn't. I have tried all the suggestions on the internet such as: updating chrome, trying a different IDE, using FireFox. None of these have helped my code carry out what I want.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome')

chrome.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oM-yAjUGO-E')
```

Comment: `executable_path` should point to the `chromedriver` location. Are you sure the one you stated is the correct location?

Comment: The location is possibly correct since the browser opens up, but if it isn't how do I find that location on mac. @0buz

Comment: If you type `which chromedriver` in a terminal, what's the output?

Comment: Which terminal are you referring to?

Comment: The command prompt [terminal](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2019/04/19/ways-open-terminal-mac/).

Comment: Well i typed it there and nothing happens. It just goes to the next line

Comment: Do you recall specifically installing `chromedriver` on your system. Note it's not the same as the Chrome browser app.

Comment: Yes I may have overlooked that fact, I have just installed chromedriver and my program works perfectly, thank you very much for your assistance, this is greatly appreciated. @0buz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone encountering this issue, please make sure that you have installed the chromedriver (or whatever driver is available for your browser). For chrome you first need to check your information and find out the version from chrome://version/
then from, https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
download the corresponding driver and copy the filepath into the the executable_path section.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have installed [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/).
The install path would typically be "/usr/local/bin", although whatever the path, that's the one to use as "executable_path"

Also remember to keep Chrome browser and chromedriver versions [in sync](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection) i.e. if you have Chrome version 81, you should install chromedriver version 81.

Answer (score 0):

I also have encountered this trouble. Before that, you're supposed to check the status code of your access. If it is 400, this station may set anti reptile which preventing any operation of reptile. I solved that by adding following code:

```
        chrome.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
      "source": """
        Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
          get: () => undefined
        })
      """
    })
```